# AS3 - Make ADDED_TO_STAGE Capture/Bubble?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

So the *ADDED_TO_STAGE* and *REMOVED_FROM_STAGE* Events do not notify ancestors in any way.  I've looked all around and can't find an answer...do I need to build a new class to do it, or is there a way to hack it into using the Capture/Bubble notification phases?

Comment: It should. Are you sure you don't have a rogue stopPropogation hanging around?

Comment: How are you verifying that these events are not being fired after their respective calls, namely `addChild` and `removeChild`.  Please share your code so that the SO community can review it.

Comment: I tested it on a fresh application using Trace and it's actually in the reference: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/Event.html#ADDED_TO_STAGE

Comment: You should post your code so we can see what you are testing/tracing.

Comment: I see why you're all confused now...I don't want to post the code since it's such a vague question, which you should probably be able to answer now that I corrected the question.  I want ANCESTORS notified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The descendants of a `DisplayObject` that is removed from the stage dispatches it's own `REMOVED_FROM_STAGE` and `ADDED_FROM_STAGE` events when their parent is removed from the display list of the stage.

So you can simply add an event listener to any descendant and have it handle those events directly.

I may be misunderstanding what you are trying to do, but in general events bubble upward from child objects to their parents. So when you say the descendants are not notified, you are correct as they are not upward on the heiarchy. However, if your goal is for a given object to know when it is added/removed to/from the display list of the stage, that can be had by listening to the specific `DisplayObject`.

So although the added/removed events do not bubble to their ancestors, there is a way to listen for their events directly.

And if you subclassed MovieClip or Sprite, you could have that class listen for the event, and then dispatch an event that does bubble to the ancestors.

However, I think it be better for us to understand better what you are trying to do as your approach might be the real issue.

Comment: Oops...I had a typo, I meant to say I want ANCESTORS to be notified.

Comment: Ok, haha, that was part of my confusion on this topic. I did add a potential approach for you, as you are correct those events do not bubble upward to the ancestors.

Comment: Sorry to waste your time, man.  You actually told me all you needed to now - there's nothing built in to do it, I have to do it manually.  Thanks!